# what is the average cost of a product, given the cost of each case and its probability

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

for the 33rd sum, part a, I did

average cost = 5[P(x<8.04)] + 6.5[P(X>8.04)]

i got 5.46 but the text says 5.11

where did i go wrong[image]

also, the answer for part b says 7.39. Is that possible, given that its supposed to be 'average' but 7.39 is greater than 6.50 (the maximum cost)?

Comment: You seem to have ignored the last sentence, where you're told very short rods are scrapped. I think you have the answer to (b) instead.

Comment: no i didnt ignore it, it says cost and since they are sold for 1, the cost is still 5, so i included it in the first term. first I thought it would be 4 instead but in that case, i should subtract the selling price from the normal rods and the long ones as well, but its not given so thats not possible.

Comment: I think the short rods  _net_ cost is only $\$4$ since they recoup $\$1$ from the sale as scrap. That might give you the text answer. I agree that there's some ambiguity in the question.

Comment: i tried that too even though the net costs for the others is not known, but i still did not get the answer. maybe its just wrong in the textbook lol

Comment: Maybe - that does happen. I agree that the answer to (b) makes no sense. For (a) the net costs for the others is $\$5$. Last thing to check might be your calculation of the probabilities (three of them for the three intervals). In any case I think you do understand the principles involved. Perhaps it's time just to move on.

Comment: I think the idea of (b) is that if a rod is too short then it is not usable. Taking a more extreme example, if you spent $\$5$ on each attempt to make an item, but $99$ out of $100$ attempts created worthless junk that couldn't even be sold for scrap, then the average cost per _usable_ item would be $\$500.$

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ denote the length of a rod and let $Z=(X-8.02)/0.04$.

For (a) you should be calculating:

$$4\text{Pr}(X<8.00)+5\text{Pr}(8.00<X<8.04)+6.5\text{Pr}(X>8.04)$$

Now, $$\text{Pr}(X<8.00)=\text{Pr}(X>8.04)=\text{Pr}(Z>0.5)=0.5-0.19146=0.30854$$

and

$$\text{Pr}(8.00<X<8.04)=2(0.19146)=0.38292.$$

Substituting:

$$4(0.30854)+5(0.38292)+6.5(0.30854)=5.15427$$

(The difference in answers is probably due to rounding errors.)

For (b) the average cost is:

$$\begin{align*}\frac{4\text{Pr}(X<8.00)+5\text{Pr}(8.00<X<8.04)+6.5\text{Pr}(X>8.04)}{\text{Pr}(8.00<X<8.04)+\text{Pr}(X>8.04)}\end{align*}$$

The denominator is $1-\text{Pr}(X<8.00)=1-0.30854=0.69146$

So the average cost is the answer from (a) divided by $0.69146$, i.e. $7.45$

Comment: +1 This answer to (b) is reasonable if it's interpreted as (total cost of all rods)/(number of saleable rods) but not if it's meant to be (total cost of saleable rods)/(number of salable rods). You and the text think the former, which is probably the right reading, but the other is defensible. The question is ambiguous.